# select column value based on boolean values multiple columns - R

Tags: r

My data looks like below,

```
df=data.frame("X1" = c(1, 0, 0), "X2" = c(0, 0, 1), "X3" = c(0, 1, 0),
           "T1" = c(21, 20, 15), "T2" = c(35, 16, 19), "T3" = c(22, 32, 16))

X1  X2  X3  T1  T2  T3
1   0   0   **21**  35  22
0   0   1   20  16  **32**
0   1   0   15  **19**  16
```

And am expecting output as below

```
X1  X2  X3  T
1   0   0   21
0   0   1   32
0   1   0   19
```

As you can see, from T1,T2 and T3 only those values are picked based on boolean values in X1,X2 and X3.

I wrote a silly code using for loop, looking for a best approach..

Comment: Your dataset and output doesn't match : ) !!!

Comment: `cbind(df[1:3],T=df[4:6][!!df[1:3]])` This should be the fastest of all the solutions given below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = c("X1", "X2", "X3")
t = c("T1", "T2", "T3")
df[, "T"] = rowSums(df[, x] * df[, t])
```

---

Explanation:

when you multiply `df[, x] * df[, t]`, you get the values you want:

```
>>> df[, x] * df[, t]
  X1 X2 X3
1 21  0  0
2  0  0 32
3  0 19  0
```

then just do `rowSums` to get the values

```
[1] 21 32 19
```

Answer (score 5):

We multiply the first three columns (binary columns) with the next three columns (0 * any value = 0) and get the `pmax` (as there is only one non-zero value per row) to create the 'T' column

```
cbind(df[1:3], T = do.call(pmax, df[1:3]* df[4:6]))
#  X1 X2 X3  T
#1  1  0  0 21
#2  0  0  1 32
#3  0  1  0 19
```

Comment: When I run your code I don't get what was requested, I get `[1] 21 16 16`

Comment: @steveb Please check the OP's logical columns.  I think the OP created the dataset wrongly while it is displayed correctly

Comment: I see, I was looking at what he printed, not how he created `df`. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thats right.. i took a minute to fix after posting.. hope now it should be fine...